# Non Capturing group lazy when pattern repeats

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture 1-2 groups in a line. If a line has a dash I want a group for before and a group for after the dash. If it does not then I would like 1 group of everything.

However, occasionally a line will start with 'Remove - ', which is a phrase I would like to ignore.

Example data:

```
| Strings |
| -------- |
| Remove - Precision Speed - Recap |
| Precision Speed - Recap |
| Remove - Precision Speed |
| Precision Speed |
```

The first two should each capture group 1: 'Precision Speed' AND group 2: 'Recap'. While the last two should only capture 1 group: 'Precision Speed'.

Right now I have `^(?:Remove - )?(.+)(?:\s*-\s*)(.*)` and it is working correctly for the first two (because there is a second dash in there I believe). For the 3rd one it is capturing 'Remove' and 'Precision Speed' and for the 4th one it isn't capturing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?:Remove - )?([^-]+)(?: - ([^-]+))?$
```

And if you're dealing with a multiline text, simply add `\r\n` to the negated character class to avoid matches across multiple lines:

```
^(?:Remove - )?([^-\r\n]+)(?: - ([^-\r\n]+))?$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/W1nDIh/1).

Answer (score 1):

Make the second `-` and surrounding whitespace optional.

```
^(?:Remove - )?([^-]+)(?:\s*-\s*)?(.*)
```